# How do I speed up mdadm raid 1 rebuild?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I use an old laptop as a NAS, and for redundancy, I have two 2TB drives in software raid 1. One of them recently failed(I believe because of a blackout at the worst time possible), and now the array is rebuilding. However, even after running

```
sysctl dev.raid.speed_limit_min=50000
```

my /proc/mdstat has

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] 
[raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdf[3] sdc[0] sdd[2](F)
1952697344 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
[=>...................]  recovery =  9.0% (177507136/1952697344) finish=29184.3min speed=1013K/sec
bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

How can I make the rebuild faster than 1000K/sec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been the USB cable I was using. After replacing the oldest USB cable, the rebuild sped up to 13000K/sec.